# Understanding how integrals of type f(x+a) works

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We know that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x+y)\,dx=2\cos(y)$$
Can we call this integral a function of $y$? Like, $f(y)= \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x+y) \,\mathrm{d}x$. In this case, does $y$ being a constant or a variable matter? Will $y$ always have to be a constant?

Comment: I think it’s a matter of taste, but I refer to terms like $y$ in this instance as a *parameter*. It can still change, so it is *like* a variable, yet something sets it apart. If it arises frequently enough, I would define a function $F(y)$ so that it’s clear I’m thinking of the integral itself as prt of the function. (I’ll emphasize again that I think it’s largely personal preference, which is why I’m leaving this as a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: What matters is that $y$ does not vary when $x$ does. Otherwise the integral would be $$\int_0^\pi\sin(x+f(x))\,dx,$$ a constant !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call this integral a function of $y$. You can see that it changes values when using $y=0$, $y=\pi/2$ or $y=\pi$, for example.

No, $y$ being a constant or a variable does not matter: You can consider $f(y)=2\cos(y)$ but also $2\cos(y)$ only by itself. $y$ being a variable or not would only matter if you consider it as being in relation to $x$ itself, i.e. y is an implicit function of x.

Comment: So, just to clear up my understanding, when we say , substitute $y+x=u$, the derivative of y with respect to x will always be zero regardless of y being a constant or a variable, because there's no relation defined between $y$ and $x$?

Comment: That is correct. In the example you have just given, $du=dx$.